# How to get strings from the user in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm very very new to PHP and I'm wondering whether there's a very easy way to get strings from the user of the web page. A bit like getline(cin, variable) in c++. While I am quite familiar with HTML, I know practically nothing about forms.

Very simple and basic answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to use a form because it is the only way to get input from the user (without having them hardcode GET variables.)

Comment: Are you trying to use your script on the command line or on a webpage?

Comment: why did you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a form.

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="myinput" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your php, check for the value in `$_POST['myinput']`.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a form like

```
<form action="reader.php">
    <input type="text" name="string">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

as soon as the user clicks the "Send" button you can read the string in `reader.php` with `$_POST['string']` where `string` is always the `name=` from the text input.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to learn about forms. It's one of the main ways to interact with PHP.

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

yourpage.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['test']))
        echo $_POST['test'];
?>
```

You can access POST form values using the global array `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Really helpful but what does the PHP that you put in mean?? Again many thanks for answering so quickly

Comment: @orano10000 What, you mean that `<?php`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get input either from the Query-String in the URL:

```
index.php?id=1234
```

These parameters will be populated in the super-global `$_GET`-array:

```
array(
    [id] => 1234
)
```

The other method is through a POST-request:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="1234">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

These parameters will be populated in the super-global `$_POST`-array:

```
array(
    [id] => 1234
)
```

For more information have a look at: [PHPs `$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php), [PHPs `$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php) and [PHPs `$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php) as well as [HTML Tutorial - Forms](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML

```
<form action="/script.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="input_field" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In script.php

```
<?php

  $valueFromUser = $_POST['input_field'];
```

Notice that the name of the key reference from `$_POST` is the same as the `name=` of the text input.

See [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: Might be worth touching on sanitizing input as well Dave, so @orano10000 gets off to a good start :)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple test you can append variables directly to the url. Call

```
http://server.com/yourscript.php?var=HelloWorld
```

In your `yourscript.php` do

```
echo $_GET['var'];
```

Not so easy for your uses. So in the long term, I think you should consider using forms ;)